# Вопрос по поводу возврата значения из функции

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
function test1() {
    return false;
}

function test() {
    if(!test1()) return false;
}
```

Возможно ли в функции `test()` просто вызвать `test1()`, и если она вернет `false`, вернуть `false` и в `test()`?

То есть

```
function test1() {
    return false;
}

function test() {
    test1(); //и без проверки вернуть false, так как вызываемая функция вернула false
}
```

Comment: `function test() { return test1(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```js
function test1() {
  return false;
}

function test() {
  return test1();
}

console.log(test());
```